# How to stop and start dropbox.app in Apple Terminal?

Tags: macos, dropbox, terminal.app

How to stop / start dropbox in the Apple Terminal?

`dropbox stop` works when using Oracle Linux, but not within Mac OS 10.6.8.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Contrary to Linux, the main Dropbox functionality is in Dropbox.app itself. You wouldn't want to kill the background daemon (`dbfseventsd`), which does not have a command-line interface. So, it's not the same as in Linux.

The safest way to quit Dropbox is to run the following:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Dropbox" to quit'
```

You can start it again by calling:

```
open -a "Dropbox"
```

Comment: This doesn't kill a hanging DropBox icon in the menu bar for me. It gives `30:34: execution error: Dropbox got an error: AppleEvent timed out. (-1712)`

Comment: @Jeroen You might have to use a kill command then, with the process ID of Dropbox. Or perhaps restart the machine.

Comment: `killall` works; see my other answer that has an alias for restarting Dropbox (first trying the friendly way, then the brutal way)

Comment: @slhck I would like to simply start the dropbox daemon when I log into a Mac via ssh, without using the GUI. Could I run `dbfseventsd`? In case, where do I find it?

Comment: @Valerio I'm not sure it's that easy. The file is `/Library/DropboxHelperTools/Dropbox_u502/dbfseventsd` for me. Does `open` variant not work? Sorry that I have no better answer.

Comment: @ slhck i tried `open` via `ssh`: i get `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810`. As expected it is not possible as deamon and GUI are together.

Answer (score 26):

In addition to the [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/648696/how-to-stop-and-start-dropbox-app-in-apple-terminal/648700#648700) by [slhck](https://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck):

When the DropBox menu icon hangs and shows the [rainbow wheel/spinning wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinning_pinwheel) then the below command will kill Dropbox:

```
killall Dropbox
```

Then you can start it with `open -a "DropBox"` like https://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck mentioned.

This is the alias I have defined for restarting Dropbox:

```
alias restartDropBox="osascript -e 'tell application \"Dropbox\" to quit';killall Dropbox;open -a \"Dropbox\""
```

Note the:

- [`\` to escape some double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111063/bash-alias-command-with-both-single-and-double-quotes)
- [chaining of commands through `;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135644/how-can-i-define-a-bash-alias-as-a-sequence-of-multiple-commands/2135662#2135662) (not `&&` as the first and second might fail)

NB: The 300% enlarged spinning wheel is from WikiMedia.
[image]

Comment: Getting `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Dropbox.app with error -600.` when restarting - but the `killall Dropbox` command worked perfectly